# app2sd via android terminal emulator?

Tags: app2sd

ok so ik this has been asked 1,000,000 times...but not like this, i have a rooted plum z550 running stock kitkat 4.4.2, i dont have a pc, this phones default internal storage is 0.89 gigs...which is shit, phone storage is like 5 gigs and i have a 16 gig external sd...by default app and app data gets stored to internal storage and these days most new apps dont have option for move to sd...how can i change default download storage without a computer or another app ie...android terminal emulator or even root browser? please help thx

Comment: You cannot change the default file system of either and how they are able to function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing the default write memory could solve your problem, see the last entry in the *Storage and Memory* menu:

[image: Settings->Storage and memory]
<sup>*Settings->Storage and memory* (click image for larger variant)</sup>